# Liouville's Extension of Dirichlet Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, gamma-function

Can we use Liouville's Extension of Dirichlet Theorem to find triple integral $\int\int\int(u^2+v^2+w^2)\space du\space dv\space dw\space  where\space u=0, v=0, w=0\space \&\space u+v+w\leq1$? Or is it restricted only to functions of the form $F(u+v+z)$?

Comment: Could you stated "Liouville's Extension of Dirichlet Theorem" here, or give a link to its statement?

Comment: I am a little confused about its statement, that's why I didn't state here...